# How I can receive Class0 (flash) SMS in my app?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I wrote app for receive SMS messages (like this example: [Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages))

Everything works fine, but I doesn't receiving class0 SMS (on screen with Ok button SMS). How I can do that?

Comment: From what are you sending the class 0 Flash SMS?

Comment: My operator is sending it to me with balance info, after each call. I think it's very useful to create a widget, and intercept this type of messages

Comment: Normally operator account balances are sent via USSD and not via SMS. Do you see the messages alongside normal SMS's you have received from mobile devices?

Comment: No, I see these messages like flash SMS. I guess you're right and it's really USSD messages. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, class 0 SMS shows onscreen immediately, and cannot be suppressed.