# listening incoming sms on android

Tags: android

the following program is my sample program for Listening incoming sms.It is created .apk file
    with out error but it does not display the message please help me.the toast does not display 
    any message if the emulator receive the message.
    My scenario is receive the sms ansd display the alert dialog box to user.that sms contanins
    email address depending on that address my app search the phone contacts and send the contact 
    number of the emailId's person as reply message

```
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent)
{
    Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
    String messages="";
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        Object[] smsExtra=(Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
        for(int i=0;i<smsExtra.length;i++)
        {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

            String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
            String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
            messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";                    
            messages += body + "\n";
        }
    Toast.makeText(context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // not  display
    }
}//onReceive

my manifastfile

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="e.x.x"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="0.1" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />



    <receiver android:name=".ex2" android:exported="true" > 
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" > 
<action    android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>



</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about manifest. Try like in this example [Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages)
I think android:priority="999" and android:exported="true" is a root of problem