# Can an Android device be a server to response SMS by Http post?

Tags: android, web-services, sms

I am going to develop an android app on mobile phone or tablet with GSM, that would be:
Step 1: When device receiving GSM SMS trigger an event of server.
Step 2: Server gets content of SMS and sender's phone number. It will carried out some computing like decryption.
Step 3: Server POST a HTTP request to a Web Service.

It will be used as a SMS register server.

Is it possible? Any problem I will meet?

Comment: This is not a public service, potential user must be our hardware products customer. Every user only need register their mobile phone once they start using iOS APP. You know, iOS doesn't allowed you retrieve phone number. But, our products need link user's phone number with their account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can capture the incoming SMS in your Android Application. You will need to write a `BroadcastReceiver` for that.

For more information on how to write one and specifically around incoming SMS - check this thread out: [Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. just be aware about the amount of requests/SMS you might get as you have more users of your system.

You might consider using multiple android devices, so the server can distribute requests (i.e. send SMS) to them.