# Mobile app: how to show the OTP my app sends in a popup without leaving my app?

Tags: android, ios, authentication, one-time-password

We've had to code an OTP based authentication. I have seen some apps, like my bank's app, which when it sends the OTP also then immediately does a quick popup of the SMS that has just arrived, so I can see the OTP *without* leaving the app. I just memorize the number, close the popup, and get on with the login inside that app.

How do they do that? Is there some iOS/Android spec I should be looking at, which allows us to similarly popup the OTP without the user having to go to the SMS screen, then come back to our app? Thanks!

EDIT: I have very useful Android suggestions. Now looking for iOS variations of these recommendations. Understand iOS has much more stringent sandboxing limitations, so the "listener" may be more complex?

Comment: You need to register SMS listener in your application that are received in the android phone..

Comment: you need to use broadcast receiver for that and you can do it through this concept

Answer (score 1):

For android you need to use SMSListener as pointed out by @rushabh.
You can check at a great example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages#7171785)

Answer (score 1):

**Some Tips to achieve  your mention task for your App.**
Step - 1 create a Login Activity with necessary field like username , password and otp and Login Button.
Step - 2 When user fill the username and password  make a web service call. with input params (username and password)
         authenticate the values if true means send your OTP number as response  else response error message.
Step  -3 if response is number means  create AlertBuilder for Pop window to show your OTP number in same Activity.
Step - 4 user saw the OTP in Login Activity itself and enters the OTP in opt area i.e (EditText).
Step - 5 When user tap the login Button authenticate the OTP value. and proceed to next Activity.

Comment: Good pseudocode. Just checking between step 2 and 3 -- the OTP can only be send as a response number to a mobile number, NOT the web service instance. As in, it won't use the web protocol to send something like a message. It *needs* to use the telephony protocol. All I need to do is to make sure my app has a "listener" that listens to the SMSes received from a number that belongs to me so my app can pick up the content (OTP number) and popup.