# What is the best way to get access to text message inbox programmatically in android

Tags: android

I have searched on many sites and blogs for my query. I am confused about what is the best way to import text messages from mobile's inbox into my application. Some recommends SmsManager and some say via content providers.

Comment: If you want access to messages already received, use the Content Provider.

Comment: I don't think SmsManager allows to import messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a content resolver.

Short explaination:

- Use [`SMSManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) to send sms. [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm)
- Use [`ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) to read all existing SMS. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494532/1724097)
- Use [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to read new incomming SMS. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7171785/1724097)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android) is a good SO question which explains how to retrieve SMS from inbox.

Comment: I cant. I need 15 reputation to vote up the answer. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: But you can accept the answer so it can help other people with the same question :) (If you think i answered your question correctly ofcourse)