# Android program to recognize text on screen

Tags: android, macros

I am creating a macro (see my previous question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121221/difficulties-writing-a-custom-macro-application-for-android),
 and that macro needs to recognize text from a certain area of the device screen while running in the background.

*Basic summary:*
The program will run in the background similar to a macro, while scanning for text in a messaging app (which I will manually open after starting the program)

Basically what it needs to do is **read all text on screen and convert it into a string**(I've got the rest of the code)

Now, I need some sort of help on the text recognition. Since I cant directly copy the text, I'd need some function to scan for text and convert it into a string.

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want your app to respond to text messages, why don't you just read the incoming messages directly? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages) has examples that are mostly correct.

Comment: @MikeM. I forgot to mention that the messaging app i would be using is Kik. Also, I suppose I could extract the messages from the sqlite database. But do you know how efficiently that would work in real time?

Comment: The end client isn't really relevant if the "commands" are sent over standard SMS. Using the examples I linked above would allow your app to receive the messages as they arrive, provided they're not blocked by another app, which can only happen on Android versions prior to KitKat. This would definitely be faster than waiting for them to get written to the Provider's database, and then querying for them. I don't know how Kik handles it messaging, though.