# BroadcastReceiver listen to SMS not working

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello I have implemented BroadcastReceiver exactly like in this post
[Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages)

but for some reason, when I try send message from one AVD to second AVD with app runing, it doesnt even print the "Message received" text to log.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<application>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsListener">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.d("SmsListener", "Message received");
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
        Log.d("SmsListener", "Message received");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msg_from;
        if (bundle != null){
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            try{
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    Log.d("SmsListener", "Message: "+msgBody);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Exception caught", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

can anyone explain where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from KitKat incoming SMS broadcast interception a bit changed. Look into this manifest, which covers both pre Kitkat and Kitkat versions:

```
<!-- SMS receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" > <!-- 999 is highest system priority, so it's hack 2147483647 -->
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> <!-- pre kitkat action -->
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" /> <!-- kitkat action -->
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

So depending on Android version you have to intercept in different way:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> <!-- pre kitkat action -->
        //<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" /> <!-- kitkat action -->

        //if it is kitkat - ignore pre kitkat action
        if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED") && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
            return;
        //if it is not kitkat - ignore kitkat action
        if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER") && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
            return;
  //blah-blah
}
```