# Auto detect inbox message and transfer that message in web server

Tags: android, web-services

Is it possible that if anyone messaged me in phone inbox and my app detects its automatically and copy it and transfer that message in web-server or store in server database? please give me a suggestion or any kind of source for doing that. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Do you mean SMS messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7171785/1594776) to know how you can listen for the incoming messages.

For Sending to server, you can use `HttpURLConnection` library.

Comment: if my app is off or close, is it possible to send to server and store database??

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If yes, you should accept the answer so that it makes it easy for the coming users to find the solution :)