# Extracting latitude and longitude coordinates from sms using App Inventor

Tags: android, google-maps, app-inventor

I basically want to extract the latitude and longitude coordinates sent as sms by gsm module to an android smart phone ...

I have written an simple app which takes latitude and longitude as input and displays on the map using **App Inventor**

[App Inventor code blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr5V1.png)
[image]

I want to basically copy the extracted latitude and longitude automatically on to the lat and long fields of my android app when ever i receive an sms from a particular number

How can I achieve this guys....

Comment: any approaches ,, any tutorials links will really be helpful

Comment: How does an example SMS text look like? Is there a delimiter between latitude and longitude? Use the [text blocks](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/text.html) to extract latitude and longitude and split at that delimiter.

Comment: A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles  
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Answer (score 0):

so you need to listen for the Incoming SMS sent by GSM Module.
Basically you need a BroadcastReceiver class to listen for incoming messages.And Extract the Longitudes and latitudes. [Check this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages) Hope this helps

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           
        if (bundle != null){
           //retrieve the SMS message received
        }
    }
}
  }
```