# How to receive incoming message on Android [MM]?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to write an app that will do something when it received a message. I have google for answer for many days and found some solution like this one: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages)  but it is not working on android 6 or marshmallow at all. So is there a way to wake up my app to do something whenever it received a message on android marshmallow?

Comment: your app has need to run time permission for read sms.

Comment: @iAndroid, yeah, i have those permission, read sms, SMS received, sent sms. But it did not work on android MM, but working on lower version like jellybean instead.

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: @iAndroid, you can check the "Link" in the description or question. I follow that link too. It work well on Jellybeans devices i have, except running on MM devices.

Comment: which device you test app? Because some device has not such functionality? Like in Mi device there is no auto detected functionality.

Comment: @iAndroid: i use emulator and galaxy s5 to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Below example work for me in MM also

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                        try {
                            if (bundle != null) {
                                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                                    Logger.e("sender Num" + senderNum);
                                    Logger.e("message" + message);
                                }
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
```

onDestroy method unregister broadcast receiver

```
unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

Comment: code is look alike to the one in the link that i test too, my friend. : (