# Pulling data from text message on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I was using the [Turbo Tax app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intuit.turbotax.mobile&hl=en), and I noticed something:

For security, it sent an OTP as a text message with a 5 digit code. 
And normally it would ask me to enter the code, but as soon as the text came in, it got auto verified.

So how would one pull data from an SMS and use it in an Android Application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to listen for incoming text messages in Android, using a `BroadcastReceiver`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7171785/4093247) answer would help you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a SMS [Broadcast receiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), Your application will be able to receive SMS events with message. You can then parse the data of the SMS received.

Comment: Oh that sounds much easier than I though. Thanks