# Receive SMS and process the content

Tags: android, ios, sms, appcelerator

I'm developing an app (iOS/Android) with SMS validation. The user receives an SMS with the access code. The app validates the code and if it is valid, enter it. So far no problem, but now my client wants the SMS that is recived to be read automatically by the app (as it does whatsapp).

Has anyone done something similar?
Is there a module that allows me to do this?

I'm working with:
Titanium Appcelerator SDK 6.0.4
IPhone / Android

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible on iOS, due to app sandboxing and other security issues. A 3rd party app simply cannot access SMS.

Comment: Thanks Losiowaty... any chance in Android ?

Comment: This is possible in Android, but not in iOS as @Losiowaty pointed out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages)

Comment: See the duplicate question for pointers for android:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages

Comment: Hey @DavidBerry i am developing using Titanium Appcelerator. The posts you mentioned are with java.

Comment: Your can use hyperloop with titanium to access Java libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this module a while ago to listen to incoming SMS:
https://github.com/m1ga/ti.miga.sms.receive

Should still work with the latest TiSDK