# Codename One:SIM detection and sms reading through app

Tags: mobile, codenameone

I want to detect SIM card and read messages like OTP messages through my app in codename one. I just created the app using codename one and I want above features in my app.

Is it possible using codename one? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can do these with native interfaces on Android but those things are impossible on other platforms since they aren't supported natively.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages   .I want add android code in my codename one app which is given on above link

Comment: You can add that code under `native/android` and define the manifest entries using the build hints `android.xapplication` and `android.xpermissions` respectively

Comment: I have added code under native/android but still its not working...do I need to change some setting or do I need to add some build hints for android if yes then mention what and where to add?

Comment: I wrote the two build hints you need to define for the build to work