# Mail notificationfor every sms i got on my android device with its content

Tags: android, sms

I would like to understand how can i make something like an app for my android phone, that will send me a mail every time i get a new SMS on my device.

Is an app the right way to do it? can i create an app that will have access to my unread SMS messages that will be able to pull their text content and send it via mail?

Ive searched for a solution online but couldnt find anything that doing exactly what im trying to do here.

Im a novice coder and this idea popped out to my head and i would like to learn how i can implement such thing if its even possible.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a pretty good idea and a good practice project. have a look at the following link to listen incoming sms messages and sending an email. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-emails-from-my-android-application you may need to look into WorkManager and Services. Good luck.