# Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages and Receiving phone number

Tags: android, kotlin, sms

I implemented this to receive incoming SMS messages

[Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages)

It gives the sending phone number. But how to obtain the receiving phone number assuming the phone supports multi sim cards ?

Comment: As far a I know SIM cards don't store their corresponding phone numbers. Just IMEI